# Problems with airflow initdb

Tags: airflow

I am new to apache airflow and while installing it on my local machine I followed the quick start guide. However, when I made it to the step where you have to initialize the database I got several problems. The main one was because I was using Python 3.9, I solved those issues by downgrading to python 3.8.6.

```
# initialize the database
airflow initdb
```

Now, while doing the same command with python 3.8.6 I am getting the following error in the terminal and I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_Union' from 'typing' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/typing.py)
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction on how to solve this issue it would be greatly appreciated. I am still new to this, so please go easy on me if this is something which is a trivial fix for you.

Comment: i found a similar case a while back : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60384306/not-able-to-setup-airflow-getting-error-while-initiating-airflow-database

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command with Python 3.8 and then try `airflow initdb` again

```
pip install apache-airflow==1.10.13 \
 --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-1.10.13/constraints-3.8.txt"
```